# How to dynamically change element alignment?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**What I am trying to do:**
I am creating a page footer using html, css, and bootstrap. When the page is open on a desktop, it looks like this (which is what I want):

[image]

But when the web page reaches the minimum width, it looks like this:
[image]

However, I would like it to look something like this when the web page has been decreased to the minimum width:

[image]

**Problem/ What I tried:**
So, I am have trouble with two things.
Problem 1: I can't seem to find a solution where I can get both the images and the text to center once there is no more room for them to be side by side.

Problem 2: I can't find a solution where I keep the size of the black jumbotron the same and that keeps the text from flowing out the bottom of it.

I tried creating a table (with text in place of the images to test it). I thought if I put the elements in a table with the images centered in the far left column and the text centered in the far left column, then, when the table got small enough, the columns would stack and the elements would be centered. But I couldn't get that to work.

I also tried adding two smaller jumbotrons within the larger one. One that holds the images and another that holds the text. But I still couldn't get the images to center properly, and there is still an issue with the text flowing out the bottom of the black jumbotron.

**What am I doing wrong, and how can I do what I am trying to do using CSS and HTML?** If Javascript is the only solution, I don't mind trying that, I just don't use it much.

**Code:**

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class = "grid">
       <div class="row">
             <div class="jumbotron" id="footerJumbotron">
                <img src="ContactImages\facebookLogo.png" id="facebookLogo">
                <img src="ContactImages\twitterLogo.png" id="twitterLogo">
                <img src="ContactImages\youtubeLogo.png" id="youtubeLogo">
                <p id="footerFont">&copy; 2016 Company Name. All Rights Reserved.<br> Built & Managed by Company Name</p>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#facebookLogo{
float:left;
width:30px; 
height:30px;
margin:5px;
}

#twitterLogo{
float:left;
width:40px;
height:30px;
margin:5px;
}

#youtubeLogo{
float:left;
width:40px;
height:25px;
margin:5px;
}

#footerFont{
float:right;
color:white;
font-size:10px;
padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px; text-align:right;
}

#footerJumbotron{
background-color:black;border-radius: 0 !important; 
height:100px !important;padding-top:30px;
}
```

Comment: Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with bootstrap grid and media queries [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/543/)

```css
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .custom-row p {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .custom-row {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something i sorted out that can then be worked on.

http://codepen.io/simondavies/pen/jqjgxL

HTML

```
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-social-wrapper">
      <div class="social-wrapper">
        <div class="social-icons"><div class="facebook"></div></div>
        <div class="social-icons"><div class="twitter"></div></div>
        <div class="social-icons"><div class="youtube"></div></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-copy">
      <p>&copy; 2016 Company Name. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

CSS:

```
  body {margin:0;padding:0;}
  footer,
  .social-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
  }
  footer:before,
  .social-wrapper:before,
  footer:after,
  .social-wrapper:after { content: " "; display: table;}
  footer:after,
  .social-wrapper:after {clear: both;}

  .footer-social-wrapper {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
  }

  .footer-copy {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .footer-copy {
    text-align: right;
  }

    .social-wrapper .social-icons {
      margin: 0px;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      width: 33.333%;
      height: auto;
  }

    .social-wrapper .social-icons .facebook {
      margin: 0 auto;
      background:blue;
       width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
    }
    .social-wrapper .social-icons .twitter {
      margin: 0 auto;
      background: red;
        width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
    }
  .social-wrapper .social-icons .youtube {
    margin: 0 auto;
      background: yellow;
      width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    }

  @media(max-width:700px){
    .footer-social-wrapper,
    .footer-copy {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
```

without a frame work like bootstrap etc.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `jumbotron`, create another element `contentWrapper` and put contents inside then add a media query for it. You need to set `width` and `margin: auto` to make it centered.

Try resizing the window width to below 800 pixels, and you will see the contents are aligned center.

```css
#facebookLogo{
  float:left;
  width:30px; 
  height:30px;
  margin:5px;
}

#twitterLogo{
  float:left;
  width:40px;
  height:30px;
  margin:5px;
}

#youtubeLogo{
  float:left;
  width:40px;
  height:25px;
  margin:5px;
}

#footerFont{
  float:right;
  color:white;
  font-size:10px;
  padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px; text-align:right;
}

#footerJumbotron{
  background-color:black;border-radius: 0 !important; 
  height:100px !important;padding-top:30px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .contentWrapper{
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class = "grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="jumbotron" id="footerJumbotron">
        <div class="contentWrapper">
          <img src="ContactImages\facebookLogo.png" id="facebookLogo">
          <img src="ContactImages\twitterLogo.png" id="twitterLogo">
          <img src="ContactImages\youtubeLogo.png" id="youtubeLogo">
          <p id="footerFont">&copy; 2016 Company Name. All Rights Reserved.<br> Built & Managed by Company Name</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Bootstrap 4** you can just use the responsive alignment classes, something like `text-xs-center text-sm-left`, Also your code is highly repetitive, consider something like this:

```css
#footerJumbotron img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#footerFont {
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
}

#footerJumbotron {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container-fluid jumbotron" id="footerJumbotron">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-sm-left">
          <img src="ContactImages\facebookLogo.png" id="facebookLogo">
          <img src="ContactImages\twitterLogo.png" id="twitterLogo">
          <img src="ContactImages\youtubeLogo.png" id="youtubeLogo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-sm-right">
          <p id="footerFont">&copy; 2016 Company Name. All Rights Reserved.
          <br> Built &amp; Managed by Company Name</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/veyytd6u/

[image: bs4 responsive alignment classes]

* no need to set a fixed height if your footer is going be dynamic (in mobile when there are 2 rows, the height must change so leave it automatic)

* consider escaping the `&` in HTML => `&amp;`